# Issue with positioning of text in tabular environment

Tags: tables

I am using tabular environment to insert subplots. Here is the output

[image]

My only issue is that I need entries in left most column to be in middle as indicated by the red arrows. It seems like a straight forward thing but somehow I am not able to fix it.

Secondly, right now individual images take more horizontal space within the table. How do I adjust their size so that they are perfect squares instead of rectangles.

Here is code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating,bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    {}&
    $\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=0.5$ &
    $\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=1$&
    $\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=2$\\
    $\rho=0$ &
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio5_Rho0}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio1_Rho0}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio2_Rho0}\\
    $\rho=0.5$&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio5_Rho50}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio1_Rho50}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio2_Rho50}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `valign` key of `adjustbox` you can get what you want (note that I used another image, as I don't have access to your images):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating,bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    &
    $\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=0.5$ &
    $\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=1$&
    $\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=2$\\
    \noalign{\smallskip}
    $\rho=0$ &
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-duck}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-duck}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-duck}\\
    \noalign{\smallskip}
    $\rho=0.5$&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-duck}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-duck}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-duck}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you suggest a way to add caption to each subplot in your solution. I get error "You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.\caption@hrule ->\hrule " when I add caption like "\adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-duck}\caption{1}"

Comment: (Untested) Maybe something like `\begin{minipage}{<your width>}\captionof{figure}{<your caption>}\end{minipage}` in an extra row (if you get an undefined control sequence `\captionof` error, load the `capt-of` package)?

Answer (score 1):

similar to [Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon) answer but with little bit shorter code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{adjustbox} % in real document remove option "demo"

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\adjustboxset{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt} % <---
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    {}&
    $\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=0.5$ &
    $\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=1$&
    $\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=2$\\
    $\rho=0$ &
    \adjustimage{}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio5_Rho0}&
    \adjustimage{}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio1_Rho0}&
    \adjustimage{}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio2_Rho0}\\
    $\rho=0.5$&
    \adjustimage{}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio5_Rho50}&
    \adjustimage{}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio1_Rho50}&
    \adjustimage{}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio2_Rho50}
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same key: `valign=c`. Since you load `booktabs`, I suggest inserting `\addlinespace` to have a blank space between the rows. Also, I think using the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` look nicer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array, booktabs,rotating,bigstrut}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \adjustboxset{valign=c}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    {}&
    $\mfrac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=0.5$ &
    $\mfrac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=1$&
    $\mfrac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}=2$\\
    \addlinespace
    $\rho=0$ &
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio5_Rho0}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio1_Rho0}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio2_Rho0}\\
    \addlinespace[1.5ex]
    $\rho=0.5$&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio5_Rho50}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio1_Rho50}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth}{ChannelContourPlot_VarRatio2_Rho50}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]