# Wide table, pictures and text issues, multicolumn, etc

Tags: tables, floats, longtable, multicolumn, cellspace

I am currently writing an internship report, and trying to sum up some information in a wide table. So far, I got this (table is wider in my doc, but width is not an issue here) :

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,english]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape,pdflscape,rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx,float,makecell,hhline,longtable}
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{||c|c|l|l|l||}
\hhline{|t:=====:t|}
\textit{\textbf{V}}         & \textbf{Photo}                                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Specifications}}                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Pros}}                            & \multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textbf{Cons}}                                               \endfirsthead
\hline
\textit{1}              & \includegraphics[height=0.11\textheight]{SQUARE.PNG}                              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Spec. 1\\Moderately long description\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Simple\\Easy to make and build\end{tabular}                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sharp edges\\Basic\end{tabular}                        \\
\hline
\textit{2}              & \includegraphics[height=0.15\textwidth]{LONG.PNG}                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Blablabla\\blablablablabla\end{tabular}        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Blablabla\\Blablabla\\Blablablablabla\end{tabular}             & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Short bla\\Not working\end{tabular}            \\
\hline
\textit{3}              & \includegraphics[width=0.1\textheight]{WIDE.PNG}                                  & Tested : size, shape, other feature                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Very nice shape\\2 is barely enough\end{tabular}       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Wrong shape tho\\Goodn't\end{tabular}  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{||l|}{\textit{4}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textheight]{SQUARE.PNG}}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tested : new shape\\Big thingie\end{tabular}                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Optimized funct.\\Stronk part\\Very good color\end{tabular}    & Wrong scale                           \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{||l|}{\textit{5}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textheight]{WIDE.PNG}}         & Tested : Adam Savage                          & Idem                                                                                                              & Oversized                         \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{||l|}{\textit{6}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textheight]{WIDE.PNG}}         & Meant to be last try                                                                      & Idem                                                                                                                  & Actual failure                            \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{||l|}{\textit{7}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textheight]{SQUARE.PNG}}   & Opening mecanism                                                                          & Soft opening                                                                                                  & Unable to be built                            \\
\hhline{|b:=====:b|}
\caption{Part versioning.}
\label{tab:PartTable}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Giving us :

[image: Code result]

We can see that :

- When we use the `tabular` environment in a cell to be able to write on several lines, the content in the cell of the 2nd column (on the same line than the `tabular` usage) cannot be vertically centered in the cell. It looks like it is only being display on the first line of the `tabular` environment ;
- Those pictures are **overlapping the cell's horizontal lines** ;
- Again, when we use the `tabular` environment, the text does not vertically center ;

What I precisely want is described as below :

- **Headline** to be horizontally centered ;
- First two **columns** (number and picture) to be horizontally (and vertically) centered ;
- All the other text (from line 2, col 3 "Spec. 1" to bottom right "Unable to be built") to be vertically centered and aligned on the left ;
- Picture not to get over the table's lines ;
- If possible, I would love to see the same margin over and under each picture, speaking about dimensions.

I have been looking through quite a lot of (already asked) questions, including those from [NAASI](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449556/issue-with-positioning-of-text-in-tabular-environment), [Michael](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474654/picture-in-latex-table-vertical-centered?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Jsg91](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170941/images-in-table-going-over-cell-lines), etc. and did not find a suitable solution to my problem.

I am fully aware that I might have missed a lot of things, either on the forum or on the internet in general, so I would totally understand a simple redirection to a related and very similar question. Any help would be highly appreciated, whether it is a suggestion, a full correction, a short comment or just a full another code compiling into the described result.

Thanks in advance, and have a lovely day. <3

Marck

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may serve as a point to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makecell,hhline,longtable}


\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\newcommand{\imageborder}{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{\imageborder}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\imageborder}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{||c|@{\hspace{\imageborder}}0c@{\hspace{\imageborder}}|X|X|X||}
\hhline{|t:=====:t|}
\textit{\textbf{V}}         & \textbf{Photo}                                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Specifications}}                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Pros}}                            & \multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textbf{Cons}}                                               \endfirsthead
\hline
\textit{1}              & \includegraphics[width=2cm, valign=c]{example-image}                              & Spec. 1\newline Moderately long description  & Simple Easy to make and build & Sharp edges\newline Basic                     \\
\hline
\textit{2}              & \includegraphics[width=2cm, valign=c]{example-image-10x16}                                 & Blablabla  blablablablabla       & Blablabla\newline blablablablabla             & Short bla\newline Not working            \\
\hhline{|b:=====:b|}
\caption{Part versioning.}
\label{tab:PartTable}
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @leandriis ! I believe I do not need my `tabularx` package anymore then, right ? And if I have some other tables in the document, do I have to change them all to `xltabular` instead of having `longtable` or `tabular` ?

Comment: ok so I have been dealing with a bunch of errors while compiling your code, but it's finally working now, so thanks a lot ! I do not know what I did wrong : I was having a lot of `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.<recently read> \endtemplate` errors, but managed to get rid of them all anyway.