# sub figures with caption on the side and on the bottom?

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I'm trying to create the following scheme in latex, where is given outcome is that some subfigures have both a caption on the bottom and on the left.
Currently, the closest thing I've got was

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock caption text

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{a}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }&
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{b}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\\
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{c}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }&
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{d}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\\
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{e}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }&
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{f}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\\
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{g}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }&
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{h}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\\
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{i}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }&
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{j}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\\
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\caption{\lipsum[2]}
\label{x}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525478/side-caption-on-subfigure), which results in *one* side figure for the whole figure.

This is an example of the desired outcome -
[image]

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449556/ issue-with-positioning-of-text-in-tabular-environment/449559#449559 can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Zarko's help, I'm putting it here for future reference

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    
    No $\mathcal{L}_{AG}$ &
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-a}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-b}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-c}\\
    With $\mathcal{L}_{AG}$ &
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-a}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-b}&
    \adjustimage{width=.25\textwidth,valign=c}{example-image-c}\\
    \noalign{\smallskip}
    &NaiveNet&
    Step 1&
    Step 2\\
    
    \end{tabular}
      \caption{This is my one big table} \label{tab:sometab}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Just after the first line of pictures (and before Whith ...) add this line:
&&&\\
to separate horizontally the two lines of pictures.