# tabularray with inserted subfloats: why counter "subfigure" doesn't start from "1" (or "a")

Tags: subcaption, subfig, tabularray

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating, makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex, belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{subfigure}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{3em}                % from makecell
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=c}   % from adjustbox
\begin{tblr}{%hlines, vlines,
            colspec={r X[c,h]X[c,h]X[c,h]X[c,h]},
            colsep=3pt,
            column{1}={cmd=\rotcell, font=\bfseries},
            row{1}={font=\bfseries},
            }
    & A & B & C & D \\[-2ex]
one
    & \subfloat[\label{fig5a1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
        & \subfloat[\label{fig5b1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
            & \subfloat[\label{fig5c1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
                & \subfloat[\label{fig5d1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}} \\
two
    & \subfloat[\label{fig5a2}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
        & \subfloat[\label{fig5b2}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
            & \subfloat[\label{fig5c2}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
                & \subfloat[\label{fig5d2}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}} \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Why numbering of `subfloat`s captions start with 41? Even if I before compilation delete files `.aux` and `.log`, the result is the same.

[image]

If i use `tabularx` table ([see answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612298/i-want-to-add-label-to-the-subplot-on-the-top-and-left-how-can-i-do-it/612301#612301)), caption numbering is correct. So I wondering, if in `tabularray` settings is missed something or it interact with `subcaption` (with `subfig` is the same) on unexpected way?

In compilation I use `tabularray` version 2021N (temporary available on *github* [see link 2021N](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/raw/main/tabularray.sty)), which is announced for September 1st.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, this may be workaround, however as package author said (in his answer), this is bug which will be handled in one of the next package version. I will wait to bug fix.

Comment: I have fixed this bug. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated on 2021-09-10**: I have added `counter` library to `tabularray` package for resetting LaTeX counters when needed.
This bug should has been fixed. You may download the latest package file from
https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/raw/main/tabularray.sty
and test whether there are other problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating, makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex, belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{subfigure}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{3em}                % from makecell
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=c}   % from adjustbox
\begin{tblr}{%hlines, vlines,
            colspec={r X[c,h]X[c,h]X[c,h]X[c,h]},
            colsep=3pt,
            column{1}={cmd=\rotcell, font=\bfseries},
            row{1}={font=\bfseries},
            }
    & A & B & C & D \\[-2ex]
one
    & \subfloat[\label{fig5a1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
        & \subfloat[\label{fig5b1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
            & \subfloat[\label{fig5c1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
                & \subfloat[\label{fig5d1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}} \\
two
    & \subfloat[\label{fig5a2}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
        & \subfloat[\label{fig5b2}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
            & \subfloat[\label{fig5c2}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}}
                & \subfloat[\label{fig5d2}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}} \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

It is a recently known bug ( see https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/discussions/83 ).

To build a nice table, `tabularray` need to measure every cell several times, therefore the counters inside the cell will be increased several times.

As David Carlisle has commented there, `tabularx` has some code to save the values of all LaTeX counters and reset them for each trial. Therefore counters in `tabularx` are correct.

I need some time to look into this problem. And it is too late for version `2021N`. I will update this answer after I have solved this problem.

Comment: Thank you for information. I already looking for package version after 2021N :-)