# Tabularray and beamer compatibility

Tags: beamer, tabularray

I'm encountering a little problem with tabularray and beamer. Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{TEST}

    \begin{tblr}{colspec={cc}}
        \visible<+(1)->{Test} & \visible<+(1)->{Test} \\
        \visible<+(1)->{Test} & \visible<+(1)->{Test} \\
    \end{tblr}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When compiled, it should result in FIVE frames. The first frame has nothing, the second one has the first *Test* word, the third has two words, and so on...

But this results in 25 frames !

I tried to identified where the problem is... so here are a couple of "research"

- If I change `tabularray` to `tabular`, it is working correctly
- If I change the overlay values to `<2->`, `<3->`, etc... as below, it is working correctly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{TEST}

    \begin{tblr}{colspec={cc}}
        \visible<2->{Test} & \visible<3->{Test} \\
        \visible<4->{Test} & \visible<5->{Test} \\
    \end{tblr}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Finally, I tried to include a counter, just to try to understand:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcounter{mycountertest}
\setcounter{mycountertest}{2}

\newcommand{\showNumber}{\arabic{mycountertest}\stepcounter{mycountertest}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{TEST}

    \begin{tblr}{colspec={cc}}
        \visible<1->{Test \showNumber} & \visible<3->{Test \showNumber} \\
        \visible<4->{Test \showNumber} & \visible<5->{Test \showNumber} \\
    \end{tblr}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the first time *Test* appears, is for a counter value of... 25 ! On the final slide, the counter is set to 120!

Is there a way to counter this problem ? I know I can use `tabular` or eventually `tabularx`, but I'm using `tabularray` for other features...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suspect that there might be some subtle incompatibilities between `tabularray` and `beamer` since the two packages are both pushing LaTeX's parsing to its limits in different ways.

Comment: @DonHosek it is not beamer, you get the same with article. tabularray processes the cells more than once but doesn't reset the counters. This looks like a clear bug to me.

Comment: I added an issue https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/116

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The counter problem was solved several days ago: I have added `counter` library to `tabularray` package for resetting LaTeX counters when needed. You may download the latest package file from [here](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/raw/main/tabularray.sty)
or wait for version 2021P scheduled on 2021-10-01.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\UseTblrLibrary{counter} %% added this line

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{TEST}

    \begin{tblr}{colspec={cc}}
        \visible<+(1)->{Test} & \visible<+(1)->{Test} \\
        \visible<+(1)->{Test} & \visible<+(1)->{Test} \\
    \end{tblr}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See also [tabularray with inserted subfloats: why counter "subfigure" doesn't start from "1" (or "a")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612334/tabularray-with-inserted-subfloats-why-counter-subfigure-doesnt-start-from)

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect !