# Tabularray - Display row one by one on Beamer?

Tags: overlays, tabularray

Following this question regarding [Tabularray and beamer compatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616435/tabularray-and-beamer-compatibility), How do you get to display a the table row by row in `beamer` ?

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\UseTblrLibrary{counter} %% added this line

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{TEST}

    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={cc},
            width=\textwidth,
        }
        \visible<+(1)->{Test} & \visible<+(1)->{Test} \\
        \visible<+(1)->{Test} & \visible<+(1)->{Test} \\
%        \visible<+(1)->{Test& Test \\ } % pb here
%        \visible<+(1)->{Test& Test \\ }
    \end{tblr}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [GitHub Issue #226](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/226) and [TopAnswers #2000](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2000) for more details.

It is easy to display a `tabularray` table row by row, column by column, or cell by cell in a `beamer` document, by using `counter` library and `cmd` key:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Show a taularray row by row}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={lll},cells={cmd=\onslide<\arabic{rownum}->}}
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
\end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Show a tabularray column by column}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={lll},cells={cmd=\onslide<\arabic{colnum}->}}
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
\end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Show a tabularray cell by cell}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={lll},cells={cmd=\onslide<+->}}
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
\end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your package is too smart not to have a clean answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use absolute frame number:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\UseTblrLibrary{counter} %% added this line

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{TEST}
        
        \begin{tblr}{
                colspec={cc},
                width=\textwidth,
            }
            \visible<+(1)->{Test} & \visible<+(1)->{Test} \\
            \visible<+(1)->{Test} & \visible<+(1)->{Test} \\
            \visible<6->{Test} & \visible<6->{Test} \\ 
            \visible<7->{Test} & \visible<7->{Test} \\
        \end{tblr}
        
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```